# .NetCore - Model Binding with MultipleViews/BindPoperty

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to use **Model Binding** on two properties, both of them with `BindProperty` to an `IList`.

I will Have **X Cells**, then for each selected cell (a bool in Cell Object), I have `1 Reference`. So in a pratical example I have **21 Cells**, **3** of them are selected, so I must select **1 Reference for each of those selected Cells**. All good until here, but when entering my **Post Handler** The **ILists** in which I'm storing are merging up, in other words, data is storing in the same IList. So, when **SelectedCells and SelectedReferences**(see below) should have 21 and 3 objects respectively, they have both 21 and the properties with the same name (e.g Id) get overwritten.

If the Views are associated to both the different view models, shouldn't the IList's be recognized as different?

```
[BindProperty]
public IList<CellViewModel> SelectedCells { get; set; }

//Was trying to play with ModelBinder type to force them to be treated as different types, unsuccessfully
//[ModelBinder(BinderType =(typeof(ReferenceViewModel)))]
[BindProperty]
public IList<ReferenceViewModel> SelectedReferences { get; set; }
```

**Views**

Cells

```
@model IList<NoPaper.ViewModels.CellViewModel>


<if include-if="Model.Count == 0">
    <alert type="Warning">
        Não existem células nesta unidade de produção
    </alert>
</if>
<if include-if="Model.Count > 0">

    <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal row">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <if include-if='Model[i].CellCategoryDescription == "Célula Robot" '>
                <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action text-center col-md-2" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <input type="hidden" class="cell-value" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
                    <input type="hidden" class="cell" asp-for="@Model[i].IsSelected" />
                    @Model[i].Name<text style="font-weight:bold;">(R)</text>
                </div>
            </if>
            <if include-if='Model[i].CellCategoryDescription == "Célula Manual" '>
                <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action text-center col-md-2" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <input type="hidden" class="cell-value" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
                    <input type="hidden" class="cell" asp-for="@Model[i].IsSelected" />
                    @Model[i].Name<text style="font-weight:bold;">(M)</text>
                </div>
            </if>        
        }
        </div>
</if>
```

References

```
@model IList<NoPaper.ViewModels.ReferenceViewModel>


<if include-if="Model.Count == 0">
    <alert type="Warning">
        Não existem referências nesta unidade de produção
    </alert>
</if>
<if include-if="Model.Count > 0">

    <div class="justify-content-center">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <text>@Model[i].CellId</text>

                    <label asp-for="@Model[i].myId"></label>
                    <select asp-for="@Model[i].myId" asp-items="Model[i].ReferencesSL" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="">--</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].myId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

</if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add name attribute to your input,.net core bind data with name attribute.For example,if you want to bind SelectedCells:

```
<input type="hidden" class="cell-value" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" name="SelectedCells[@i].Id"/>
```

if you want to bind SelectedReferences:

```
<input type="hidden" class="cell-value" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" name="SelectedReferences[@i].Id"/>
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks a lot. Can you explain me why the binding didn't occur as expected? I assumed, since they are different Models the binding should happen without any problems.